# "directory name is too long"?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, directory-listing

I recently formatted and reinstalled Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.

Now, when I recursively search for a file from the command prompt (eg,`dir c:\somefile.* /s`) I get a lengthy list of invalid folder names:

[image: img]

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no question in your "question", and there are a lot of duplicates: [In Windows 7, how do I get around the "The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder" error?](https://superuser.com/q/705417/241386), [filename too long error windows 7 64bit](https://superuser.com/q/818711/241386), [File name too long to copy but doesn't say which one](https://superuser.com/q/533221/241386), [How to rename a (too) long file name](https://superuser.com/q/638123/241386), [How to delete a file in Windows with a too long filename?](https://superuser.com/q/45697/241386)

Comment: There are 2 possibilities. 1st one is the folder name is really long, you have folders tree with extreme depth. This variant is already answered/commented on. 2nd possibility is the disk structure is damaged, there is cyclic folder reference in it (subfolder is referenced to parent folder). If so you must to fix this error with some disk structure checking/repairing utility (chkdsk, for example). !!! DO NOT TRY to delete such errorneous folder !!! it can damage the whole parent folder. PS. The last subfolders differs from repeated middle one - it seems we have 1st variant.

Comment: Never seen a file path like those, Application Data folder is repeated, something went wrong, reinstall again.